# Problem with sending value of variable with RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In variable search_for I've got the string value of the value I'm searching for. But I cannot pass it via RequestDispatcher to jsp. What am I doing wrong?

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("my.jsp?search_for");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soution 1 :

```
request.setAttribute("paramName", search_for);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("my.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

**or**

Soution 2 :

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("my.jsp?paramName="+search_for);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I've tried both of them alongwith response.redirect and jsp foward, but none of them works